# how to make junit TestSuite parallel

Tags: unit-testing, junit, test-suite

I have created several `junit` test suites which include several test cases.
Looks like as below:

```
@RunWith(Suite.class)

@Suite.SuiteClasses({

    HttpAPICreationTest.class,
    HttpAPIVerifyTest.class,
    HttpAPIDeletionTest.class
})

public class HttpAPITestSuite {   
}   

@RunWith(Suite.class)

@Suite.SuiteClasses({

    HtmlSeleniumScriptBatchCreationTest.class,
    PagingVerificationTest.class,
    HtmlSeleniumScriptBatchDeletionTest.class
})

public class PagingTestSuite {   
}
```

Now I want to execute my `HttpAPITestSuite` and `PagingTestSuite` in parallel, and for now, `HttpAPICreationTest.class`,    `HttpAPIVerifyTest.class`, `HttpAPIDeletionTest.class` are executed serial, not in parallel> Also, I don't want to break their order.

So how can I make my suites run parallel and keep the original order for their inner test cases: run `HttpAPICreationTest.class` and `HtmlSeleniumScriptBatchCreationTest.class` in parallel, and keep the case of `HttpAPICreationTest.class` always before `HttpAPIVerifyTest.class` and `HttpAPIDeletionTest.class`.

Answer (score 2):

If you are using maven, use Surefire forks. If you want behavior part parallel, part serial, then you would need to execute the plugin multiple times, with different settings. But generally speaking, the jUnit runners/plugins are not well suited for "run tests as a graph", test ordering is done much better way in TestNG.

```
  <plugin>
    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
    <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>2.19.1</version>
    <configuration>
        <forkCount>3</forkCount>
        <reuseForks>true</reuseForks>
    </configuration>
  </plugin>
```

More documentation: http://maven.apache.org/surefire/maven-surefire-plugin/examples/fork-options-and-parallel-execution.html

---

**Edit**: if you are running tests from Idea, then Idea (2016.3) has its own settings in Run tests configuration (and does not pick up maven settings). And it supports only one global settings per tests execution (serial/method_fork/class_form + fork count)

Comment: Hi, thanks for the quick answer. I will check whether it works.